# How to output a "show" command result from Cisco ASA in playbook?

Tags: ansible, config, cisco, asa

Relatively new to Ansible but I'm just wondering what the syntax looks like if I want to run a command on an ASA like `show run | i opmanager` and then print the output. I have put a pause in because after the output is printed I want it to wait before continuing.

I have an ASA I want to configure with the playbook to see if i can deploy new SNMPv3 credentials to whilst also removing an old set.

```
This task removes any existing ManageEngine config for SNMP
  tasks:
    - name: Show remainging opmanager config
    asa_command:
      commands: show run | i opmanager 
      register: ManageEngine
      pause:
        prompt: "Do you want to proceed? (yes/no)"
        register: confirm
```

Comment: First you would have to fix the above yaml because there are many erros in a few line. Please make sure your indentation is correct for each parameter and seperate each task in its own list item (i.e. `pause` and `asa_command` should be separate tasks for example. As is, it is quite difficult to make sure what you're trying to do exactly and the exact intent. Then, as a quick solution to see more output from a task, you can run ansible in verbose (e.g. `-vvv`) mode. But a better long term solution is to simply add a debug task to display your registered value (i.e. `ManageEngine`).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question

> I'm just wondering what the syntax looks like

you may have a look into the Ansible Collections documentation [Run arbitrary commands on Cisco ASA devices](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/cisco/asa/asa_command_module.html), the documentation of `debug`_module to [Print statements during execution](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html) and the `pause`_module to [Pause playbook execution](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pause_module.html).

```yaml
  # This task removes any existing ManageEngine config for SNMP

  tasks:

    - name: Show remaining opmanager config
      asa_command:
        commands: show run | i opmanager 
      register: ManageEngine

    - name: Show result
      debug:
        msg: "{{ ManageEngine }}"

    - name: Pause until confirmation
      pause:
        prompt: "Do you want to proceed? (yes/no)"
```